# Retrieving / updating individual MPNowPlayingInfoCenter properties

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, mpnowplayinginfocenter

In a basic audio `AVPlayer` instance, we're playing back an HLS stream and setting the Now Playing info (successfully), but cannot access the properties of the `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` that are being set.

The `category` and `active` status of our `AVAudioSession` and are [receiving remote control events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16301753/612189) without issue as well.

```
NSMutableDictionary *properties = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[properties setObject:title forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
// Set several other properties

MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *center = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
[center setNowPlayingInfo:properties];

// Works! The lock screen successfully shows the title and other properties

NSLog("%@", [center nowPlayingInfo]);
```

The `NSLog` prints a very default-looking dictionary containing only a `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate` of `0` - which is not accurate anyway as the audio is playing back during the log.

We want to [retrieve the currently-set dictionary of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21691159/612189), update a few, and set them again (for things like album art updates, play/pause timings, etc). What are we missing?

Answer (score 0):

try the following to retrieve the current properties;

```
 NSMutableDictionary *playInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo] ;
```

And set/update properties as follows;

```
[playInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 1.0f] forKey:MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate];
[playInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:songDuration] forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];

[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo = playInfo;
```

Comment: Thanks @MDB983- but this is the same approach I have in the first 6 lines above to set the values. When you log `[[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] nowPlayingInfo]` after your code, do you get the full feature set printed out?

Comment: I can inspect a breakpoint in my code, and yes, playInfo shows a number of key/value pairs. Obviously these are values that you have set previously.

Comment: Here is an Log i just grabbed from a player i have. info {
    MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate = 1;
    artist = "Corinne Bailey Rae";
    artwork = "<MPMediaItemArtwork: 0xb7b1910>";
    playbackDuration = "215.4579591836735";
    title = "Put Your Records On";
}    All of these properties were previously set elsewhere.

Comment: Right - not `playInfo`, but the actual `defaultCenter`'s `nowPlayingInfo`... immediately after setting the value, I can't access the `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`'s values. Really strange.

Comment: That is odd, just changed my nslog to read  NSLog("%@", [center nowPlayingInfo]); after setting the new values and i'm getting all the new values back.